# else no me funciona

Tags: python

eh empezado en python hace nada 1 dia como mucho,y e estado probando a hacer un archivo que te responda a una pregunta,la pregunta es quien?.Ya que hay una broma que dices:
-Ayer me encontre una serpiente
-Quien?
-Yo
-No que quien te a preguntado
Quiero hacer algo asi.Este es el codigo,pero me dice que yo no esta definido

```
    quien = input('Quien?')

if quien == yo: 
    print('ok') 
elif quien == tu: 
    print('ok') 
elif quien == el: 
    print('ok')
elif quien == nosotros:
    print('ok')
elif quien == vosotros:
    print('ok')
elif quien == ellos:
    print('ok')
```

Comment: tu código debería de dar error

Comment: Esos pronombres deberían ir entre comillas .Si no sabes nada de lenguajes informáticos mírate algún video en [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2FCfQj-9ig&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BlvPxziopYZRd55pdqFwkeS&index=1) que siempre se hace menos pesado que leer un libro que creo que es lo que estas haciendo.

Answer (score 7):

Debes comparar con el tipo de datos correcto, es decir, un `string`. Para ello debes introducir el argumento del `if` entre comillas simples. El ejemplo correcto sería el siguiente:

```
quien = input('Como se llama')

if quien == 'yo': 
    print('ok') 
elif quien == 'tu': 
    print('ok') 
elif quien == 'el': 
    print('ok')
elif quien == 'nosotros':
    print('ok')
elif quien == 'vosotros':
    print('ok')
elif quien == 'ellos':
    print('ok')
```

Saludos